# disabled "label" and disabled "input" Selenium

Tags: javascript, html, css, selenium, disabled-input

I am testing with Selenium. Two (2) Page elements are disabled, one is "input" the other is "label".
I have attached pictures to show how they look like being disabled.

But Selenium driver cannot assert the "label" type as disabled, although it clearly is.

Is something wrong with FE developer code to define "label" and "input" as disabled elements?

My code to assert is:

```
Assert.assertFalse(driver.findElement(By.xpath("abc").isEnabled());
```

Input element:

[image]

Label element:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### HTML `<input>` disabled Attribute

A disabled `<input>` element is unusable and unclickable. At times the `disabled` attribute is set to keep an user from using the `<input>` element until some other condition has been met (like selecting a dropdown, checkbox, etc.).

As per the first image:

[image: disable_input]

The `<input>` with *name* attribute set as *destinationCity* is assigned the **disabled** attribute possibly to force the user to fill up the *originCity* first.

Similarly, as per the second image:

[image: disable_label]

The `<label>` with *for* attribute set as *settingsDangerousGoods*  which controls the following `<input>` element with *id* attribute set as *settingsDangerousGoods* is assigned the **disabled** attribute possibly to force the user to fill up the previous mandatory fields.

However, a *JavaScript* could remove the disabled value, and make the `<input>` element usable.

---

### Update

The attributes of the `<label>` is applied for the element with *id* attribute set as `for='settingsDangerousGoods'`which is the following `<input>` element. However, you won't interact with a `<label>` but you would most likely interact with an `<input>` element. See the [docs](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#isEnabled--):

```
isEnabled(): 

Is the element currently enabled or not? This will generally return true for everything but disabled input elements.
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation but that does not specifically answer my question. Selenium "can" detect the <input> element disabled but it "cannot" find out the <label> element is disable, so if you assert the second image, <label>, Selenium tells you that it is "Enable"! How can I tackle this issue?

Comment: @abbas Checkout the answer update and let me know the status.

Comment: So now, <label> does not have any "id" attribute. Should it be a good idea to ask FE developer to add "id" attribute? Then I can easily figure out if the <lable> element is enabled or disabled. Right?

Comment: @abbas Why would you expect an _id_ attribute of a `<label>` element which you don't need to interact? Moreover `id` attribute is not mandatory. You have _cssSelector_ and the _xpath_ locator strategy as well to locate elements.